# React, handling states where a property can have 3-4 possible states

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a state like:

`this.state = {status: 'disconnected'}`

Now, `status` can be any of *'disconnected', 'connected'* or *'connecting'*. How to best handle this case? Should I just compare the state with string literals like 'connected' or 'connecting' wherever I have to or there is a 'react' way of handling this case?

I want to list down all the possible values for `state.status` under one umbrella.

Comment: You can just set up a basic state machine within your component and that should be fine. Comparing against an array of string literals is a fine solution. Where is this status being determined? Is it triggered/changed off of an ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

I think most people would just create an object with the statuses.

```
const STATUSES = {
  CONNECTED: 'CONNECTED',
  CONNECTING: 'CONNECTING',
  DISCONNECTED: 'DISCONNECTED'
};
```

And then use these troughout your app. This will prevent that you accidentally compare to a typo in a literal.

Comment: That's my go-to way of handling such scenarios, but I was just wondering if React has some unique way of handling this.